# methods/ print Histogram of random numbers

Tags: java, random

> You will develop a program to count the number of times each number in the range is generated. Your program will generate 100 numbers in the range [0, 9] and you will print a histogram similar to the histogram shown below.

```
 0  ********
 1  *********** 
 2  ******
 3  ****************
 4  **************
 5  *****
 6  ************
 7  ***********
 8  ********
 9  *********
```

> To print the histogram shown above, your program must record the number of times each number is generated.

I am trying to pass the num and count into the print method and then pass it through the switch statement to print it as asterisks. but it is giving me an error. Advice?

Here is the error I am getting:

> required: int,int   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in length /tmp/java_9JsuaS/RandomSrv.java:55:
>   error: method print in class RandomSrv cannot be applied to given
>   types;
>                     System.out.print("9 " + this.print());
>                                                 ^

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomSrv
{

    public void genNums(int total)
    {

        for(int counter = 0; counter < total; counter++) //counter for the random gen nums//

        {
            int UPPER_BOUND = 10;//max number it will go to: 9

            int count0 = 0; //stores counter//

            int count1 = 0;
            int count2 = 0;

            int count3 = 0;

            int count4 = 0;

            int count5 = 0;

            int count6 = 0;

            int count7 = 0;

            int count8 = 0;

            int count9 = 0;

            int count = 0;

            Random randObj = new Random(); //creating randoms object//
            int num = randObj.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);//num ranges 1-10//
            print(num, count);
            switch (num) //counts it into catagories//
                {
                case 0: count = count0++;
                    System.out.print("0 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 1: count = count1++;
                    System.out.print("1 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 2: count = count2++;
                    System.out.print("2 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 3: count = count3++;
                    System.out.print("3 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 4: count = count4++;
                    System.out.print("4 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 5: count = count5++;
                    System.out.print("5 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 6: count = count6++;
                    System.out.print("6 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 7: count = count7++;
                    System.out.print("7 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 8: count = count8++;
                    System.out.print("8 " + this.print());
                    break;
                case 9: count = count9++;
                    System.out.print("9 " + this.print());
                    break;
                }

        }
    }
    public void print(int num, int count) //converting them to astericks//
    {
    for(int x = 0; x < count; x++)
        {
        System.out.println("*");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is too long and complicaed to the desired problem. I would suggest thinking of Array such as int[10] (from 0-9) each position in the array refers to its value for example: array[i++]  each time you have the digit with the i value the i position is raised by one. The printing in the end will be done by running over that array.

Comment: It doesn't tell you how to generate the numbers. You could just [generate 4 each time](https://xkcd.com/221/) and then print 100 asterisks in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
int[] counts = new int[10];   // this array will hold the count for each number (0-9)
Random rand = new Random();   // the Random object

/* Loop 100 times getting a random number each time, and add to the corresponding count */
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    switch(rand.nextInt(10))
    {
        case 0: counts[0]++; break;
        case 1: counts[1]++; break;
        case 2: counts[2]++; break;
        case 3: counts[3]++; break;
        case 4: counts[4]++; break;
        case 5: counts[5]++; break;
        case 6: counts[6]++; break;
        case 7: counts[7]++; break;
        case 8: counts[8]++; break;
        case 9: counts[9]++; break;
        default: break;
    }
}

/* Loop 10 times printing the asterisks for each count */
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
     System.out.print(i + " ");
     for(int j=0; j<counts[i]; j++)
         System.out.print("*");
     System.out.println();
}
```

Run it here (online compiler): http://rextester.com/UKSB96871

Comment: You can write `counts[rand.nextInt(10)]++` instead of switch (and maybe extract index as a var).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
Map<Integer, String> groups = Stream.generate(() -> rand.nextInt(10))
                                    .limit(100)
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                                                   Collectors.mapping(e -> "*",
                                                                                      Collectors.joining())));

groups.forEach((number, hist) -> System.out.println(number + " " + hist));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple way:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomSrv {
    private final int UPPER_BOUND;// max number it will go to
    private final int TOTAL;
    private final int[] numbers;
    private final int[] counter;

    public RandomSrv(int upperBound, int total) {
        this.UPPER_BOUND = upperBound;
        this.TOTAL = total;
        this.numbers = new int[this.TOTAL];
        this.counter = new int[this.UPPER_BOUND];
        this.genNums();
    }

    private void genNums() {
        Random randObj = new Random(); // creating random objects
        for (int counter = 0; counter < TOTAL; counter++) {
            // counter for the
            // random generate numbers
            int num = randObj.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
            this.numbers[counter] = num;
            this.counter[num]++;
        }
    }

    private void print(int count) // converting them to asterisks
    {
        System.out.print(String.format("%d: ", count));
        for (int x = 0; x < counter[count]; x++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void printAll() {
        for (int count = 0; count < this.UPPER_BOUND; count++) {
            this.print(count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] commandArguments) {
        int upperBound = 10;
        int total = 100;
        new RandomSrv(upperBound, total).printAll();
    }
}
```